# Connecting an HTML button with Javascript object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to build a searchable database that will allow a user to type in the name of a state and see a small subset of that state's laws (traffic laws, age of consent, conceal and carry laws, etc.). I'm getting confused on how a user submitted string will interact with my Javascript objects. I have seen people submitting questions regarding adding user-submitted integers or concatenating but what I am trying to do is slightly different.

I am able to assign the user-submitted text as a variable via the getElementById method but now I'm lost. My question is this: How do I connect that user submitted variable with my objects' key values in Javascript so that when a user types in "Minnesota" and clicks the find button it retrieves and displays my Javascript data (which is information about Minnesota's state laws stored as object keys)?

Here is a subset of the **HTML** in question:

```
<div class="formDiv">
<form id="searchbox" action="">
  <!--Search field-->
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Ex: Minnesota"></input>
  <!--Submit button-->
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search"></input>
</form>
</div>
<!--Where I want the Javascript object to be displayed-->
<div class="answer"><p></p></div>
```

And here is the **Javascript** with just one object for simplicity:

```
var Minnesota = {
  name: "Minnesota",
  consent: 18,
  openBottle: true,
  deathPen: false,
  conceal: "Conceal & Carry",
  txtDriveBan: true,
  talkDriveBan: false
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").on('click', function(){
  var State = document.getElementById("#search");
  //At this point, what do I write to display Minnesota's information stored in the object?//
  });
});
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: check this http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go I implemented this fiddle for you with how I'd handle what you need. I changed the data structure so that the state names are the keys...

http://jsfiddle.net/yc7w364t/

```
var stateData = {
    "minnesota" : {
      consent: 18,
      openBottle: true,
      deathPen: false,
      conceal: "Conceal & Carry",
      txtDriveBan: true,
      talkDriveBan: false
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my data structure to put the state names as keys, although it doesn't seem to be working in that js fiddle link.

Comment: edit: nevermind, something was wrong with my browser. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! sounds good. An upvote or check would be great :P hah trying to raise my rep ^^

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough "rep" to upvote this so I gave you a check.

Answer (score 0):

The keys in your object should be the name of the state. Then you can do this:

```
var states = {
    "Minnesota": {
        consent: 18,
        openBottle: true,
        deathPen: false,
        conceal: "Conceal & Carry",
        txtDriveBan: true,
        talkDriveBan: false
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit the form.
  var State = document.getElementById("#search");
  var answerString = '';
  for (var key in states[State]){
     answerString += '<p>' + key + ': ' + states[State][key] + '</p>';
  }
  $('#answer').html(answerString);
 });
});
```

Note that you should change the div that will contain the answer to have `id` "answer", not `class` "answer".

Comment: I also thought the same as far as the data structure he was using :) And the id for answer as well actually. Twinsies.

Comment: Good call. I also saw your solution and I realized I needed to add `e.preventDefault` to mine.